# Extracting contents from string in unix

Tags: unix, sh

When I run,

```
ps aux | grep dexter | grep ruby | grep -v grep
```

This is what I get,

```
dexter  3285  0.0  0.0  31652  5356 ?  S  00:01  0:01 ruby /home/dexter/script.ruby
```

I have the whole output in a string say,

```
s= dexter  3285  0.0  0.0  31652  5356 ?  S  00:01  0:01 ruby /home/dexter/script.ruby
```

I need to extract /home/dexter/script.ruby from the string. How can i achieve this in unix?

Comment: Unix is an operating system. Your question pertains to the Bourne shell programming language, i.e. `sh`. I have added the appropriate tag.

Answer (score 1):

Use awk

```
ps aux | grep dexter | grep ruby | grep -v grep | awk '{print $11}'
```

Comment: thanks for your help but i need some alternative to awk. The output from awk does not get transferred to my script some how.

Comment: Especially since you invoke Awk anyway, this can be refactored quite a bit. `ps aux | awk '/[d]exter/&&/[r]uby/{print $11}'`.

Comment: Use a command substitution to capture the result: `s=$(ps aux | awk '/[d]exter/&&/[r]uby/{print $11}')` would place the result in `$s`.

Comment: The string you want appears to be `$12` in the sample output, though.

Comment: For improved accuracy you could say `awk '$1 == "dexter" && $11 == "ruby" { print $12 }'`

Comment: @triplee  In your first comment, why do you use a character class for `d` and `r`?

Comment: Rather than `$12` or `$11`, it is probably easier to use `$NF` to get the last field.

Comment: Because some versions of `ps` with some options will contain the text of the awk script, and I don't want it to match itself.

Answer (score 0):

you could use [bash parameter substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html)

```
 echo '/'${s#*\/}
```